# Is it possible to establish a relationship on multiple tables usign Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a huge table with tens of millions of rows and inserting/querying is becoming very expensive.

I considered partitioning by range, but unfortunately I can't always provide a range when querying it.

So what I'm thinking of right now is to split it in multiple tables, but I have one problem - how can I query all the tables in the same time using Eloquent relationships?

For simplicity let's consider we have a `User` model and a `Posts` model. On the `User` model we have a relationship like this:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function posts(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
}
```

If the `posts` table is split into `posts`, `posts_a`, `posts_b`, `posts_c` how would the relationship look like?

The end goal is to retrieve the correct posts even if the records are split across multiple tables.